# Cannot convert input to timestamp in JSF

Tags: jsf, timestamp

I'm trying to save a Date and Time thats entered by a user as a Timestamp in JSF but I keep getting this error: "Cannot convert 23.02.19 12:00 of type class java.util.Date to class java.sql.Timestamp"

This is my code thats supposed to converrt the input "23.02.2019 12:00" to a Timestamp.

```
<h:inputText value="#{eventMB.eventTo.datum}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm" />
    </h:inputText>
```

Comment: `java.sql.*` types doesn't belong in the model in first place. Are you using plain vanilla JDBC instead of e.g. JPA? Your real problem should be solved in the model layer not in the view layer.

Comment: @BalusC okay I'm new with JSF so I could skip converting the String in the model layer by using this but I'll just convert the String in the model layer then, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Can you please answer the question with a Yes or No? Only then we can help you further in the correct direction.

Comment: Conversion from ui-input (technically strings) to model type of java.util.Date should be in theJSF layer. Only in your DAO you should convert the java.util.Date to a java.sql.TimeStamp (but it is easier if you use JPA and have the persistence layer do this for you

Comment: Can't you tell if you're using plain vanilla JDBC or not? You need to at least tell how exactly you're obtaining data from DB and filling your model classes, before we can answer how exactly to correct your model so that you can continue using `<f:convertDateTime>` as documented. To be clear: your JSF code is totally fine. It's only your model that's wrong, but this is nowhere detailed in the question. One example which explains your problem would be that the `datum` is a `java.util.Date` property which is filled like `eventTo.setDatum(resultSet.getTimestamp("datum"))`.

Comment: Any progress???